# Why is attributeChangedCallback called twice?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

I'm building a simple custom element, using the [custom elements polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements). I've registered an attribute to be "watched" (using `observedAttributes()`), and when I change the value of this attribute, the function `attributeChangedCallback` is called twice.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<my-component id="compo" foo="bar"></my-component>

<button id="myBtn">Change attribute value</button>
```

Here is my component definition:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['foo'];
  }
  
  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('[my component] attribute', attrName, 'changed from', oldVal, 'to', newVal);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);

// Change value of the component attribute
$('#myBtn').click(() => $('#compo').attr('foo', 'baz'));
```

On that page, when I click on the button, I have the following logs in the `console.log`:

> [my component] attribute foo changed from bar to baz
>
> [my component] attribute foo changed from bar to baz

Why is `attributeChangedCallback` called twice? How can I avoid it?

The JSFiddle of this example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/czo1355c/

Thanks.

Comment: I get two changes, but from null -> bar and then bar -> baz in your JSFiddle example.

Comment: indeed, but - as explained in my comment to @ikram-shah answer, the problem seems to be on the polyfill. Chrome v54+ is implementing `customElements` natively, so the polyfill is not used, and the function is only called once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `custom-elements.js` polyfill is an alpha version and not stable yet, you should use instead the [polyfill from WebReflection](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element):

- [`document-register-element.js`](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element/releases) v1.3

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed your jsfiddle, and it's not actually called twice on button click, but firstly called when the `<my-component id="compo" foo="bar"></my-component>` is rendered, as you are setting the value of `foo`; and secondly when you clicked the button.

You can also debug it on jsfiddle, using developer tools, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find and debug the function.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I've tested my JsFiddle on the latest version of Chrome, and indeed the call is made only once. On my professional computer, I'm using Chrome v53, that does **not** implement the customElements (added in v54), so the polyfill is used and **there**, the call is made twice. So the problem is on the polyfill!